# Extract hexadecimal number from string

Tags: python, string, hex

I want to extract hexadecimal number from a string. For example, the string is: `OxDB52 Message 1 of orderid 1504505254 for number +447123456789 rejected by Operator`. I want to extract hexadecimal `OxDB52` part. I know it can be done checking for `0x` in string.

But is there any cool pythonic way to extract hexadecimal number from string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use regex pattern with [`re.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) method:

```
re.findall(r'0x[0-9A-F]+', your_string, re.I)
```

this will give you a list of all the hexadecimal numbers in `your_string`.

Demo:

```
>>> s = '0xDB52 Message 0x124A orderid 1504505254 for number 0xae45'
>>> re.findall(r'0x[0-9A-F]+', s, re.I)
['0xDB52', '0x124A', '0xae45']
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming words are properly separated

```
[x for x in my_string.split() if x.startswith('0x')]
```